# How to decrease size of mouse pointer in testcafe

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

How to decrease the size of the mouse pointer in testcafe.. Below is code which I wrote but not working...

```
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture test
.page http://example.com
.beforeEach(async t => {
await disableCursor();
})

const disableCursor = ClientFunction(() => {
var styleElement = document.createElement('style');
styleElement.innerHTML = '.cursor-hammerhead-shadow-ui {width:10px; height:40px }';
document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
});

test('test', async t => {
await t.click(Selector('body > div > p:nth-child(3) > a'))
await t.click(Selector('#header > div.navigation > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a'))
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To decrease the mouse pointer size, do the following:

1. Specify cursor selector: `#root-hammerhead-shadow-ui.root-hammerhead-shadow-ui .cursor-hammerhead-shadow-ui`.
2. Use the `!important` flag in CSS properties.

As a result, the code below replaces the default cursor with a red square:

```
const resizeCursor = ClientFunction(() => {
    var styleElement = document.createElement('style');
    styleElement.innerHTML = '#root-hammerhead-shadow-ui.root-hammerhead-shadow-ui .cursor-hammerhead-shadow-ui { background: red !important; width:40px !important; height:40px !important }';
    document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
});
```

If you want to change the cursor to your own image, try this CSS property: `background-image`.

Note, since in a general case, it is hard to predict what unexpected results adding this CSS may produce, I suggest that you carefully check this prior to integrating this solution into your project.

See also: [ClientFunction](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/clientfunction/)

Comment: Thanks Airich... with your code square red box is displaying instead of smaller cursor... Tried to change background image but no luck ..

styleElement.innerHTML = '#root-hammerhead-shadow-ui.root-hammerhead-shadow-ui .cursor-hammerhead-shadow-ui { background-image: url("pointer.png") Iimportant; background: red !important; width:40px !important; height:40px !important }';

let me know where I need to keep image file...